# how to create a function with switch statement javascript

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I am currently starting  studying JS and I need to do the follow exercise with switch statement.

```
function colorMix (color1, color2){
  if ((color1 === 'red' && color2 === 'blue') || (color1 === 'blue' && color2 === 'red')){
    return 'violet';
  } else if ((color1 === 'red' && color2 === 'yellow') || (color1 === 'yellow' && color2 === 'red')){
    return 'orange';
  } else if ((color1 === 'blue' && color2 === 'yellow') || (color1 === 'yellow' && color2 === 'blue')){
    return 'green';
  } else {
    return 'need to mix two diferent colours'
  }
}

 let myColor = colorMix('blue', 'blue');
  console.log(`The color created is: ${ myColor}`);
```

that is what I got so far but it's not working:

```
let color1 = '';
let color2 = '';

let firstColour = ((color1 === 'red' && color2 === 'blue') || (color1 === 'blue' && color2 === 'red'))
let secondColour = ((color1 === 'red' && color2 === 'yellow') || (color1 === 'yellow' && color2 === 'red'))
let thirdColour = ((color1 === 'blue' && color2 === 'yellow') || (color1 === 'yellow' && color2 === 'blue'))

function colorMix (color1, color2){
switch (color1, color2){
  case 'firstColour':
    return 'violet';
    break;
  case 'secondColour':
    return 'orange';
    break;
  case 'thirdColour':
    return 'green';
  default:
    return 'error';
  }
}

let myColour = colorMix('red', 'blue');
console.log(`Colour created is ${myColour}`)
```

I don't know how to make the switch statement to recognize the colors I introduce. Any thoughts? thanks!!!

Comment: `switch (color1, color2)` isn't valid, what did you expect? Please add the error's your facing.

Comment: @0stone0 - It's valid, it's just basically the same as `switch (color2)`. The wonders of the comma operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `(color1, color2)` evaluates to `color2` because the comma is an [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) here. So that is not useful for a `switch` statement.

One way to make it work, is to translate color *strings* to color *numbers*, in such a way that the principle colors (red, yellow, and blue) are powers of 2. If they are added together (or better OR'd together), the other color numbers are found.

Here is how that could be done:

```js
const colorNames = ["none", "red", "yellow", "orange", "blue", "violet", "green", "black"];
const colorNums = Object.fromEntries(colorNames.map((name, i) => [name, i]));

const colorMix = (color1, color2) => colorNames[colorNums[color1] | colorNums[color2]];

console.log(colorMix("blue", "red")); // violet
// Order does not matter
console.log(colorMix("red", "blue")); // violet
// Mixing a color with itself does not change it
console.log(colorMix("orange", "orange")); // orange
// Can mix an already mixed color again
console.log(colorMix("violet", "yellow")); // black
```

## Explanation

```
const colorNames = ["none", "red", "yellow", "orange", "blue", "violet", "green", "black"];
```

Here we create an array of color names. The *index* at which a name occurs in this array, is its unique identifier. The principle colors are on indices that are powers of two: 1, 2 and 4. If we would write the indices as binary numbers, the above array looks like this:

| index in binary | color name |
| --- | --- |
| 000 | none |
| 001 | red |
| 010 | yellow |
| 011 | orange |
| 100 | blue |
| 101 | violet |
| 110 | green |
| 111 | black |

This array can be used to give the color name that corresponds to an index. Notice how "orange" (011) combines the binary bits of "red" (001) and "yellow" (010), taking a "1" when either of the mixed colors has a "1" in the same position of the binary representation.

The following statement creates the reverse mapping (from name to index):

```
const colorNums = Object.fromEntries(colorNames.map((name, i) => [name, i]));
```

The `.map()` creates pairs of name and index (the above table but with the columns swapped). `Object.fromEntries` uses this information to create a plain object:

```
{
    none: 0,
    red: 1,
    yellow: 2,
    orange: 3,
    blue: 4,
    violet: 5,
    green: 6,
    black: 7
}
```

With these two conversion objects we can now make a nice color mixer function:

```
const colorMix = (color1, color2) => colorNames[colorNums[color1] | colorNums[color2]];
```

The two colors are each converted to their number using `colorNums`.

These two numbers are combined using the binary OR operator (`|`). This will give the number of the color we want to get.

Finally that value is translated back to a color name, using the `colorNames` array.

The rest of the script illustrates how the function can be called:

- The order of the arguments does not matter
- When both input colors are the same, the behaviour is different from what you did: the color is just returned unchanged, reasoning that mixing a color with itself does not change the color.
- Already mixed colors can be mixed again (This is of course a simplification of reality where mixing colors is influenced by the *amount* of paint that is mixed with another color. The relative amounts influence the outcome).

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by combining the colors into a key, and switching on that key:

```
function colorMix (color1, color2){
    const key = color1 < color2 ? color1 + " \t " + color2 : color2 + " \t " + color1;
    switch (key) {
        case "blue \t red":
            return "violet";
        case "red \t yellow");
            return "orange";
        case "blue \t yellow";
            return "green";
        default:
            return return "need to mix two diferent colours";
    }
}
```

That assumes colors names won't have space/tab/space in them.

That works because we're using strings we can combine into a single key. If we didn't, or the expressions were more complex, then while it would be **possible** to do this with a `switch`, there'd be no good reason to, you'd basically be writing the same thing as the `if`/`else if` chain (because in JavaScript, that's all `switch` is — unlike some other languages with similar syntax), and the result would be **really** surprising to anyone else reading the code.

For completeness, here's that general case:

```
// DON'T DO THIS
switch (true) {
    case (color1 === 'red' && color2 === 'blue') || (color1 === 'blue' && color2 === 'red'):
        return 'violet';
    case (color1 === 'red' && color2 === 'yellow') || (color1 === 'yellow' && color2 === 'red'):
        return 'orange';
    // ...
}
```

That works because case labels are expressions in JavaScript, which are tested in order (except for `default`), with the first match being used.

But again, don't do that. :-D

You might also consider a lookup table:

```
// Creates a key for the two colors, where the colors are always
// in lexicographical order (so we don't have to worry about the
// argument order)
const colorKey = (color1, color2) => color1 < color2 ? color1 + "\t" + color2 : color2 + "\t" + color1;

const colorMix = new Map([
    [colorKey("blue", "red"), "violet"],
    [colorKey("red", "yellow"), "orange"],
    [colorKey("blue", "yellow"), "green"],
]);

// ...

function colorMix (color1, color2){
    const color = colorMix.get(colorKey(color1, color2));
    return color ?? "need to mix two diferent colours";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! it worked by changing the ```switch (true)``` parameter. I know there might be a better ways but I was asked to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using too much comparisons with a `switch` statement, you could get all colors in an array and sort them, then check with a normalized order.

```js
function colorMix(...colors) {
    colors.sort();
    if (color[0] === 'blue' && color[1] === 'red') return 'violet';
    if (color[0] === 'red' && color[1] === 'yellow') return 'orange';
    if (color[0] === 'blue' && color[1] === 'yellow') return 'green';
    return 'need to mix two diferent colours';
}
```

A different approach with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
function colorMix(...colors) {
    const
        mixedColors = {
            violet: new Set(['blue', 'red']),
            orange: new Set(['red', 'yellow'])
            green: new Set(['blue', 'yellow'])
        };

    return Object.keys(mixedColors).find(c => colors.every(Set.prototype.has, mixedColors[c]))
        || 'need to mix two diferent colours';
}
```

And finally one without statemes, just with an accessor

```js
function colorMix(...colors) {
    const mixed = {
        blue: { red: 'violet', yellow: 'green' },
        red: { yellow: 'orange' }
    }
    colors.sort();
    return mixed[colors[0]]?.[colors[1]] ||'need to mix two diferent colours';
}
```

Comment: Switch doesn't do many comparisons like ``if``, it jumps straight to the result, in fact it's not recommended to use expressions inside the switch.

Comment: @Gamedroit, *"jumps straight to the result"* ... can you provide proof for this claim? The [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-switch-statement-static-semantics-early-errors) does not describe it in that way. In step 4 of that procedure you can see that the cases are one by one compared.

Comment: I have not seen the arrays yet but I'll check it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm using bitwise to add the colors, so no matter the order they will always generate a unique ID, with switch I check the color id which would be the sum of the ids of the two colors.

```js
function getColorIndex(color1, color2) {
    const colors = {
        "red": 1,
        "blue": 2,
        "yellow": 4 // next will be the double (n * 2) e.g: "violet": 8
    }

    return color1 !== color2 ? colors[color1] | colors[color2] : -1;
}

function colorMix (color1, color2) {
    switch (getColorIndex(color1, color2)) {
        case 3: // red + blue (1 + 2 === 3)
            return "violet";
        case 5: // red + yellow (1 + 4 === 5)
            return "orange";
        case 6: // blue + yellow (2 + 4 === 6)
            return "green";
        case -1: // getColorIndex will return -1 if colors are equal
            return "need to mix two diferent colours";
        default:
            return `Unrecognized colors: ${color1} + ${color2}`;
    }
}

let myColor = colorMix('blue', 'blue');
console.log(`The color created is: ${ myColor}`);

myColor = colorMix('omg', 'idk');
console.log(`The color created is: ${ myColor}`);

myColor = colorMix('red', 'yellow');
console.log(`The color created is: ${ myColor}`);
```